# Apply penalty function to non-linear least square estimation convergence with bounds in R - package minpack.lm

Tags: r, nls, levenberg-marquardt

I want to perform a non-linear least square estimation using the function `nlsLM` from the package `minpack.lm`.

I want to impose an upper and a lower bound to the estimation to force the algorithm to find the solution within a specific support.

Something along these lines:

```
library(minpack.lm)
mydata <- data.frame(x=c(0,5,9,13,17,20),y = c(0,11,20,29,38,45))
myfit <- nlsLM(formula(y ~ a*x), data = mydata, start=list(a = 2.5), lower = c(a = 0), upper = c(a = 5))
summary(myfit)
```

My question is:

is it possible to apply a penalty function to `nlsLM`, so to avoid that the algorithm returns a corner solution? e.g. in my example a is not equal to 0 or 5.

Caveats:
I am exclusively looking at a solution with the package `minpack.lm`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To implement this [barrier function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrier_function#:%7E:text=In%20constrained%20optimization%2C%20a%20field,region%20of%20an%20optimization%20problem.) which approaches infinity as `a` approaches 0 from the right or 5 from the left:

```
log(a)^2 + log(5-a)^2
```

as a penalty we form the objective function

```
(y[1] - a*x[1])^2 + ... + (y[n] - a*x[n])^2 + (0 - log(a))^2 + (0 - log(5-a))^2
```

like this

```
n <- nrow(mydata)
mydata0 <- rbind(mydata, 0 * mydata[1:2, ])
nlsLM(y ~ c(a * x[1:n], log(a), log(5 - a)), mydata0, start = list(a = 1))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. It is not all clear to me. First, why I need to create mydata0? Second, it looks to me that the barrier is at log(a), and log(5-a), not log(a)^2 and log(5-a)^2, am I correct? Third, can you explain how e.g. log(5-a) creates a penalty? Suppose for instance "a" goes to 4.8, this means that we are applying a penalty of log(5-4.8) = -1.61? And this penalty to what is applied, the RSS? Fourth, can you clarify how bounds are used? To create e.g. a barrier function between -1 and 1, should I replace log(a) and log(5-a) with e.g. "(-1-a-0.05)" and "(1-a-0.05)"

Comment: Have added explanation.  Be sure to read the link.

Comment: The added explanation is extremely helpful and clear, and the link is a great reference. Thank you very very much. Still, it is unclear to me what is the logic behind mydata0. Why I need two new rows in my dataset, and why these have to contain values equal to zero?

Comment: So that we can form the loast two terms in the objective function.

Comment: Ok now it is all clear. I have accepted your answer. Indeed, thank you very much.